# Is there any way to fill mysql information_schema.TRIGGERS.created = now()

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I'm planning to update mysql from **5.7** to **8.0** in amazon RDS

Once i'm running util.check_for_server_upgrade() im receiving such errors for all my triggers

> Trigger db_name.tbl_name.trigger_name does not have CREATED attribute.

Is there any way to fill MySQL information_schema.TRIGGERS.created = now();

expect solution to recreated all triggers ?

i tried also to run

> UPDATE `TRIGGERS` SET `CREATED`='2020-01-01 10:10:10';

but receiving

> Access denied for user 'dbadmin'@'%' to database 'information_schema'

Comment: INFORMATOIN_SCHEMA tables are views, not static tables. View cannot be updated.

Comment: *Once i'm running util.check_for_server_upgrade() im receiving such errors for all my triggers* This may be upgrade procedure issue (I doubt but check user manual). Or you perform the upgrade wrongly (perform the upgrade from the beginning with the accuracy of each letter). AS the last chance - save all triggers codes, then remove triggers, upgrade tables and recreate triggers back.

Comment: @Akina no this is before upgrade precheck command, I have to fix them before proceeding to upgrade step

Comment: @Amen Did you ever resolve this? I'm in the same boat.

Comment: @MarcSaegesser Yes - so there is no way to update that information_schema tables, what i did is just exported via phpmyadmin and re imported triggers and that resolve my issue.

Comment: @Armen Do you really have to fix them? I got them in precheck too but they're just Notices not Errors, so they wont' prevent actually updating